# Mapping through Strapi data doesnt work in React

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I was following the [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/integrations/react.html#create-a-react-app) on strapi and react but i get this console error:

**this.state.restaurants.map is not a function**

If i console log the data it gives me this response

[image]

But trying to display them on frontend its not working

**This is with the Fetch method**

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    restaurants: [],
    error: null,
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const parseJSON = (resp) => (resp.json ? resp.json() : resp);

    const checkStatus = (resp) => {
      if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
        return resp;
      }
      return parseJSON(resp).then((resp) => {
        throw resp;
      });
    };
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    try {
      const restaurants = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/restaurants", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
      })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(parseJSON);
      this.setState({ restaurants });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { error, restaurant } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
            <li key={restaurant.id}>{restaurant.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**This is Axios method**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  // State of your application
  state = {
    restaurants: [],
    error: null,
  };

  // Fetch your restaurants immediately after the component is mounted
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/restaurants');
      this.setState({ restaurants: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { error, restaurant } = this.state;

    // Print errors if any
    if (error) {
      return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.restaurants.map(restaurant => (
            <li key={restaurant.id}>{restaurant.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**My strapi roles on Public have the checked mark to find and findOne the same as on this [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start.html).**

**Console log of the response**
[image]

Comment: Please try `this.state && this.state.restaurants && Array.isArray(this.state.restaurants) && this.state.restaurants.map(restaurant =>`. This should help ensure that `.map` is definitely applied to an array, I think.

Comment: @jsN00b now i get blank frontent and this errors `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.` and `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Comment: The 'port closed' and 'connection' errors appear related to the API call. Would you please add `console.log` for `response` just after this line: `const response = await axios.get`? Let us investigate the `response`.

Comment: @jsN00b ive added the image in the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get restaurants from `response.data` but the response have an object
with  `data: { data: ... }`.

Solution:

```
this.setState({ restaurants: response.data.data });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, also i would like to add that to show the actual name of the restourant i had to add `attributes` so it goes like this:
`{this.state.restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
            <li key={restaurant.attributes.id}>{restaurant.attributes.name}</li>
          ))}`

Comment: But i dont understand why its happening like this, i followed the documentation exactly step by step and those additional tweaks should be in the docs...